# Не получается вывести точную структуру как на примере

Tags: php, mysql

В БД хранятся данные (уникальный идентификатор, значение, версия).

Таблица имеет следующий вид:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` ( 
`ident` varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
`value` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
`version` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
UNIQUE KEY `ident` (`ident`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251
```

На вход скрипта в GET приходит запрос в следующем формате:

```
ident[0]=<IDENT_0>&value[0]=<VALUE_0>&version[0]=<VERSION_0>&....
&ident[N]=<IDENT_N>&value[N]=<VALUE_N>&version[N]=<VERSION_N>
```

Считается, что в БД всегда хранятся актуальные данные. 
Скрипт должен обработать данные поступившие на вход и на выходе вернуть сериализованный массив с 3мя ключами:

1. delete - список идентификаторов, которые пришли в запросе и отсутствуют в БД
2. update - список значений и версий по идентификаторам, где версия в БД стала больше чем версия пришедшая в запросе
3. new - список значений и версий по идентификаторам, которые отсутствуют в пришедшем запросе, но есть в БД

Пример структуры массива который может получиться на выходе скрипта:

```
array ( 
    'delete' => array ( 
        0 => 'ident1', 
        1 => 'iden3', 
    ), 
    'update' => array ( 
        'ident2' => array ( 
           'value' => 'some value 1', 
           'version' => 56, 
        ), 
    ), 
    'new' => array ( 
        'ident4' => array ( 
           'value' => 'some value 44', 
           'version' => 1, 
        ), 
        'ident5' => array ( 
           'value' => 'some value 567', 
           'version' => 2, 
        ), 
    )
)
```

Вот мой скрипт.

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db( "test", $db );
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

$sql_request = 'SELECT * FROM `data`';
$result = mysql_query( trim( $sql_request ) );

$update = array();
$delete = array();
$new = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {

    if ( in_array( $row['ident'], $_GET['ident'] ) )
        {
            $tmp_position = array_search( $row['ident'], $_GET['ident'] );

            // Если есть такой идентификатор, проверяем версию "больше"
            if ( $row['version'] > $_GET['version'][ $tmp_position ] )
                {
                    $update[ $row['ident'] ] = array(
                                                        'value'     => $row['value'], 
                                                        'version'   => $row['version'],
                    );
                }

            unset( $_GET['ident'][$tmp_position] );
            unset( $_GET['value'][$tmp_position] );
            unset( $_GET['version'][$tmp_position] );
        }
    else
        {
            $new[ $row['ident'] ] = array(
                                            'value'     => $row['value'], 
                                            'version'   => $row['version'],
            );

        }
}

$delete = array();
if ( !empty( $_GET ) )
    {
        foreach( $_GET['ident'] as $key => $line )
            {
                $delete[] = $_GET['ident'][$key];
            }
    }

$all_result = array(
                    'delete'    => $delete,
                    'update'    => $update,
                    'new'       => $new,

);

print_r( $all_result );
```

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ:

```
Array
(
    [delete] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [update] => Array
        (
        )

    [new] => Array
        (
            [ident2] => Array
                (
                    [value] => some value 1
                    [version] => 56
                )

            [ident4] => Array
                (
                    [value] => some value 44
                    [version] => 1
                )

            [ident5] => Array
                (
                    [value] => some value 567
                    [version] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

Спасибо.

Comment: А в чем неточность то? Массив delete?

Comment: delete и update не выводятся.